# Why comparing a string(double quoted) to an integer code works?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
test="2"
if [ "$((test & 0x1))" != 0 ]; then
  echo "First bit is set"
else
  echo "First bit is not set"
fi
```

In this example, if statement contains double quotes and compared against an integer, this works well. But is this correct? Are double quotes right here?
Works well even without the double quotes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash#6697781

Comment: The duplicate's title talks about variables, but the discussion extends to any context where the shell evaluates a sequence of tokens.  The *value* of quotes is to prevent the shell from doing whitespace splitting and wildcard expansion on the resulting value, which of course won't happen anyway if the value is a single number. But your expression should probably avoid `[` entirely and just use the arithmetic truth value; `if $((test & 0x1)); then`

Comment: Thanks @tripleee
I couldn't get much out from the references posted because i feel this is a different question. Can you please let me know why the code I posted works?

Comment: `2&1` is 0, and `0 != 0` is obviously false (`!=` does *string* comparison, btw. Doesn't matter here but normally you'd use `-ne` for integer comparison).

Comment: Or, as suggested above, the arithmetic truth value, where `$((whatever))` is true if `whatever` does not evaluate to zero.

Comment: Double quotes don't form strings. Whatever you are quoting is *already* a string, because the shell doesn't have separate data types: everything is a string. Double quotes simply provide automatic escaping of *every* character contained therein; `"foo"` is equivalent to `\f\o\o`.